# Send File From Java to C# using Socket

Tags: c#, java, android, sockets, file-transfer

Can anyone give me a small tutorial on how to send file from java server to c# client and on receive complete acknowledgment message from c# to java. Actually I'm new to C# and dont know how to do socket programming. I'm stuck in it since long. Tried many codes. Some codes receive incomplete files some stuck in infinite loop. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks

**EDIT**
Here is what I have tried:

C# Server:

```
{

            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.131");
            // use local m/c IP address, and 

            // use the same in the client


            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 5600);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 5600...");
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");
        m:
            clientSock = myList.AcceptSocket();

            //clientSock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout,10000);


            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + clientSock.RemoteEndPoint);

            //byte[] b = new byte[100];
            //int k = clientSock.Receive(b);
            string fileName = "hello.wav";


            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(clientSock);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(networkStream);

            //read file length
            int length = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

            if (networkStream.CanRead)
            {
                BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + fileName, FileMode.Create));
                int receivedBytesLen = -1;
                byte[] clientData = new byte[4096 * 5000];

                receivedBytesLen = networkStream.Read(clientData, 0, clientData.Length);
                bWrite.Write(clientData, 0, receivedBytesLen);

                 do
                {
                    receivedBytesLen = networkStream.Read(clientData, 0,clientData .Length);
                    bWrite.Write(clientData, 0, receivedBytesLen);
                } while (receivedBytesLen > 0);

                bWrite.Close();
                networkStream.Close();


            }


            Console.WriteLine("Client:{0} connected & File {1} started received.", clientSock.RemoteEndPoint, fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} received & saved at path: {1}", fileName, receivedPath);


            Recognizer_2 recognizeVoice = new Recognizer_2(clientSock);
            recognizeVoice.recognize_wav(); // Acknowledgement 
            Console.WriteLine("\nResult Sent to the Client");
            goto m;
        }
```

Java Client:

```
        Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.131", 5600);


        BufferedReader response_Stream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        File f = new File(mFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


        bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(buffer);

        outputStream.flush();

        String final_Result_String = "";

        if (response_Stream != null) {
            String respose_text = "";
            while ((respose_text = response_Stream.readLine()) != null) {

                final_Result_String += respose_text;

            }

        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), final_Result_String, 1)
                .show();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: socket means almost nothing: which protocol you want to use? Is it defined, is something custom?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) I.e. please show us some code, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I have to submit my assignment today. Please help me if you can..:(

Comment: Please check the edited question now. Updated some code

Comment: An unrelated suggestion, why not use a loop instead of using `goto` in the server code?

Comment: Also, in the server code you do not seem to check for errors.

Comment: I'm adding code from different sources again and again and all time confusing. All the things are jumbled right now in my mind..:S

Answer (score 0):

There is no dependance between the languages used by the server or the client.

Just the structure of the data is important !

You should search for some tutorials on socket programming with C#.
For example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using

But the language doesn't matter, understand how the data is formatted when sent on the network.

Edit: you should add a byte or two in the data indicating the length of it. It's not because you dont have data to read once that all the data has been received.

Comment: thanks. But I am stuck somewhere in code. Unable to receive complete file.

Comment: Maybe you don't use a good test to know when to stop reading. Available bytes in the buffer is not enough, add the length to the data you send.

Comment: May be... Any decent solution you have??? What should I write in the loop condition???

Comment: Server side: Use the first two bytes to be the length of the packet (without this two bytes) and then write the file. // Client side: read first two bytes, then keep reading (or wait for bytes) as long as you don't get the good numbers of bytes

Comment: And a good solution would be to launch a timer so that you don't wait forever if the connection is lost for example during the transmission. If no character is available and the timer has elapsed, then you stop reading and return an error or whatever you want to indicate a time out.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. 
Can you give me a small piece of code for java client and c# server??
Just sending and receiving procedure..!!! M totally confused right now.

Comment: I have done the string transfer quite well but unable to handle file transfer..:S